# If statements in Batch for strings don't return true?

Tags: string, batch-file, comparison, batch-processing

```
:start
net view
set nick=
echo.
echo.
echo If you want to select a common target, enter one of the following:
echo (computer1)
echo (computer2)
echo (computer3)
set /P target="Enter one of the above computer names (without \\):
IF "%target%"=="(computer1)" do(
set nick=(computer1)
goto shortcut
)
IF "%target%"=="(computer2)" do(
set nick=(computer2)
goto shortcut
)
 IF "%target%"=="(computer3)" do(
    set nick=(computer3) 
   goto shortcut

)
ELSE goto shutdown
```

The above code is a program that is supposed to allow you to type in a shortcut to store a computer name in the variable nick.

I'm very new to batch, FYI.

When I run the program, the first if statement executes no matter what (even when %target% is a different value).  How can I reslove this?  I've done thorough research with comparing strings and none have worked.

P.S. I need to use nick in the :shutdown page so I really need that value to be set based on what the user inputs.  Also, the (computers) aren't part of the program; they're actual computer names that I replaced for the sake of the privacy.

Thanks!

Comment: By the sentence "the first if statement executes no matter what", do you mean that variable 'nick' becomes '(computer1)' after your code is executed?

Comment: @Fumu7 Yes, the variable nick is set to (computer1) no matter what value the user inputs.

Comment: My bad!  Forgot to change the strings in if statements.  Probably more understandable now @Fumu7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `IF "%target%"=="(computer1)" do(` should be

   IF "%target%"=="(computer1)" (
2. `set nick=(computer2)` (and alike) should be

   set nick=^(computer2^)
3. `ELSE` has wrong synax, should be `) ELSE (`
4. missing labels

Comment: Thanks, removing the "DO" keyword did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
:start
net view
set nick=
echo.
echo.
echo If you want to select a common target, enter one of the following:
echo (computer1) = home
echo (computer2) = guy
echo (computer3) = andre
set /P target="Enter one of the above computer names (without \\):"

IF "%target%"=="home" set nick=(computer1)
IF "%target%"=="andre" set nick=(computer2)
IF "%target%"=="guy"   set nick=(computer3)
IF "%nick%"=="" goto shutdown
goto shortcut

:shortcut
   Rem program for shotcut may be placed here
   echo "%target%"
   goto end

:shutdown
   Rem program for shutdown may be placed here

:end
```

I simplify IF-block of your code.

As JosefZ mentioned, usage of "do" in your code is wrong (syntactic error).

That error cause to ignore 'first if statement' of your code, and make next line "set nick=(computer1)" to be executed. This is the reason why it looks "the first if statement executes no matter what".